# Target Packages (sutton/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I am facing this warning error while doing sudo apt update, I think some files in the source.list.d is being more than once that's what causing the error. I don't want to mess with the system and want an expert advice which things should I remove so that my system remain safe.
I am using ubuntu 20.04 Focal

```
W: Target Packages (sutton/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target Packages (sutton/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target Packages (sutton/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target Translations (sutton/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target Translations (sutton/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (sutton/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (sutton/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (sutton/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (sutton/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (sutton/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target CNF (sutton/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target CNF (sutton/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target Packages (sutton.simon/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target Packages (sutton.simon/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target Packages (sutton.simon/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target Translations (sutton.simon/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target Translations (sutton.simon/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (sutton.simon/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (sutton.simon/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (sutton.simon/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (sutton.simon/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (sutton.simon/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target CNF (sutton.simon/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target CNF (sutton.simon/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target Packages (sutton/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target Packages (sutton/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target Packages (sutton/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target Translations (sutton/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target Translations (sutton/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (sutton/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (sutton/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (sutton/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (sutton/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (sutton/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target CNF (sutton/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target CNF (sutton/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:1
W: Target Packages (sutton.simon/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target Packages (sutton.simon/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target Packages (sutton.simon/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target Translations (sutton.simon/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target Translations (sutton.simon/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (sutton.simon/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (sutton.simon/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (sutton.simon/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (sutton.simon/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (sutton.simon/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target CNF (sutton.simon/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
W: Target CNF (sutton.simon/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list:3
```

```
 ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v165)
"   /etc/apt/sources.list.d
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../                                                                                                                                                                                                        
./
cuda-ubuntu2004-11-7-local.list
cuda-ubuntu2004-11-7-local.list.save
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.save
maarten-baert-ubuntu-simplescreenrecorder-focal.list
maarten-baert-ubuntu-simplescreenrecorder-focal.list.save
oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list
oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list.save
oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list
oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list.save
ros-latest.list
ros-latest.list.save
teams.list
teams.list.save
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
"sources.list.d" is a directory                                                                                                                                                          8,1           All
```

Comment: Do not show pictures of text please. For example the sources list. Cut and past the text into the body of the question so it can easily be read and searched. This also applies to the error messages.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David I am using ubuntu 20.04, I have attached the source.list.d file , I think I have to remove oem but not sure which one to comment out   oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list or oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list.

Comment: @user535733 Yes, this post gave me an idea what is the problem and how to solve this but not sure which one should I remove                                                               oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list
oem-sutton.simon-baara-meta.list.save
oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list
oem-sutton.simon-ballantine-meta.list.save
ros-latest.list

Comment: If it was me all the OEM ones use the # in front of the text and they are commented out. You can always remove the # latter if you want that entry to be used.

Comment: HOW I SOLVED IT. I went to the directory and use vs code for reviewing the difference between both files , then found out that they are same , hence removed one and now things are working fine.